# Spring Security not sending samesite=none with JSESSIONID

Tags: spring-security, jsessionid, samesite

This is how my websecurityconfig is described:

```
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterBefore(corsFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class) //adds your custom CorsFilter
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/ping/get").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/updatePassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/resetPassword").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .failureHandler(failureHandler())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessHandler((httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, authentication) -> {
                    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                })
                .permitAll()

        ;
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(
                        new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200")
                );
        http.headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(
                        new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                        );
    }
```

and the cors filter i've defined the header for samesite=none as follows

```
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest req= (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.getHeader("origin"));
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access-control-allow-origin,content-type");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "xsrf-token");
        res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None");
        if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

But whenever i'm calling the login endpoint, i'm only receiving httponly,secure but nnot samesite=none with my JSESSIONID cookkie. How do i make this work?
i've tried all different filter from answers of other questons but none of them work.
The issue is only on chrome. It would be helpful if there is any workaroud also. Recently chrome removed the samesite flag which could be disabled. need to solve this in order to create a webview for my site.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the SameSite attribute when using [Spring Session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/index.html) with a [custom `CookieSerializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-custom-cookie.html).

```java
@Bean
public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID");
    serializer.setSameSite("None");
    serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$");
    return serializer;
}
```